# making a string word equal to a char?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

just wondering if this is possible,

I would like a string input equal to a char, when the input button is pressed.

so at the top i define WLAN_SSID

```
#define WLAN_SSID       "abc"
```

I have also initialized the input which changes depending on the buttons pressed on the device.

```
String input = "abcdefg";
```

and somewhere below in the code I have :

```
char *ssid = WLAN_SSID;
```

I need *ssid to stay as char, but is there anyway to make it equal to the String 'input'?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can not* assign `WLAN_SSID` to a `char*` because string literals are of type `char const[N]` (with a suitable `N`) which happily decay into `char const*`s but refuse to be assigned to `char*`s. If you really need to deal with a `char*`, you'll need to allocate sufficient space and copy the value into this memory. Of course, when changing it you'll also need to release the memory appropriately. For example

```
char* make_ssid(char const* value) {
    static std::unique_ptr<char[]> memory;
    std::size_t n = strlen(value);
    memory.reset(new char[n + 1]);
    strncpy(memory.get(), value, n + 1);
    return memory.get();
}
char* ssid = make_ssid(WLAN_SSID);
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: any system which calls itself "C++" has to support the above, even though it may be necessary to use custom classes and functions for missing standard library facilities. ... and this has nothing to do with van Neumann architecture: the C++ standard mandates the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to allocate space for the `char[]`.

```
ssid = malloc(sizeof(char) * (input.length() + 1));
```

Then you need to use [`String::toCharArray()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray) to copy the characters into the buffer.

```
input.toCharArray(ssid, input.length());
```

And then later, when you're done with `ssid`, you need to discard the memory you allocated for it.

```
free(ssid);
```

You may also need to discard the original value of `ssid` before reusing it, but I don't know enough about Arduino to be sure.

Comment: `new[]` would be better in C++ (if it wasn't admittedly broken in the GNU AVR toolchain)...